# the meaning of "how" in "How do you know?"

Tags: wh-questions

[thefreedictionary.com](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/How+do+you+know%3F):
**(1)** *How do you know*?

I couldn't find in dictionaries the meaning of "how" that (1) would be appropriate for.
The standard meaning of "how" is "in what way" but here, as far as I understand, "how" means "from what source".

Comment: [correction: I'm interesting in making up, ing] They are fine. Aren't basically the same thing in your language?

Comment: "in what way" = "from what source".

Comment: Answer for (1) at Merriam-Webster: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/how. We don't do proofreading here, so I've removed your questions (2) and (3).